# When I need to specialize the typename I declared in my template class, what arguments I must use?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class for thread-safe vector:

```
template <class T>
class SharedVector {
    std::vector<T> vect;
    CRITICAL_SECTION cs;
    SharedVector(const SharedVector<T>& rhs) {}
public:
    typedef typename std::vector<T>::size_type SizeType;
    SharedVector();
    void PushBack(const T& value);
    void PopBack();
    SizeType size();
    const T& operator[](int index);
    void erase(int index);
    void Lock(); 
    void Unlock(); 
    virtual ~SharedVector();
};
```

Then I want to use it in my client manager for TCP server to delegate some 
responsibilities from client manager to this vector:

```
class TCPClientManager {
    TCPClientManager(const TCPClientManager&) {}
    TCPClientManager& operator=(const TCPClientManager&) {}
    SharedVector<Connection*> connections;
public:
    TCPClientManager();
    SharedVector<>::SizeType size(); //here is the problem
    void addConnection(const Client&); 
    void breakConnection(int); 
    void deleteConnection(int); 
    void Lock();
    void Unlock();
    ~TCPClientManager();
};

typename SharedVector<>::SizeType TCPClientManager::size() {
    return connections.size();
}
```

I need to declare the type of retrieving value. Compiler said that it was too few arguments for template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide a type argument for the SharedVector template:

```
SharedVector<Connection*>::SizeType size(); 
....
SharedVector<Connection*>::SizeType TCPClientManager::size() {
    return connections.size();
}
```

Because that `Connection*` type is not a template parameter in TCPClientManager, but an explicit chosen type, you don't need to put `typename` before `SharedVector<Connection*>::SizeType`

Answer (score 0):

(In addition to litb, really)

You should typedef your container; i.e. `typedef SharedVector<Connection*> ConnectionPool;`. This would allow you to write `ConnectionPool::size_type`.

Note: container::size() should return a `container::size_type`, not `container::SizeType`. This makes the container STL-compatible. For the same reason, the iterator class should be `container::iterator`, adding elements is done by `container::push_back(container::value_type const&)`, etc.